# What's the most important life lesson?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

#### Important Life Lessons:

---

Life can be a confusing game at times. Here's some important lessons you should follow:

1. **Time stops for no man** - Life is always changing, before you know it, there could be whole new generations before your eyes!
2. **There is order in chaos** - Life may seem confusing, but there is order hidden in the chaos. All it takes is a bit of time for the patterns to reveal themselves.
3. **Close the gaps with those around** - It's important to stay tight with those closest in life. Get rid of the gaps to keep those around close.
4. **See the bigger picture** - You will progress further through life if you don't focus on the individuals, but scan the whole as a collection.
5. **Keep going** - You will be presented with new challenges in life, but keep going with what has worked so far and things will once again become clear.

But the most important life lesson:

Well, that's for *you* to find out yourself...

---

[image]

---

$$\huge\text{What is the most important lesson in life?}$$

---

<sub>[Google Sheets link of grid](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqK8XO1PnnIROA0-x6A4XN36wNOugzWrj8KCx3EivQY/edit?usp=sharing)</sub>

Comment: Looks fun. Makes me wish i was at home on my laptop so i could try it.

Comment: @JLee could technically be solved on phone, but all I'll say is a computer would be much easier, who knows, might still be unsolved later! :P

Comment: Sounds like perhaps Conway's Game of Life may reveal something?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName perhaps... why not investigate ;)

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been having something of a rough day, and it made me smile.

Comment: @gregsdennis always happy to make someones day a little better :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is

> "Life is a beautiful puzzle!"

---

Solution:

> The first hint tells us that "life is always changing", and before we know it, there could be "new generations before our eyes". This is a pun on Conway's Game of Life, in which an initial configuration changes with each mathematical iteration of the rules, which is known as a "generation".

Here's where

> the grid at the bottom comes in. The grid is a valid pattern in Conway's Game of Life, and if we heed step 2's advice to wait "for the patterns to reveal themselves" and advance the pattern for two generations, we reveal the following 7x7 array of 3x3 patterns:
>  [image]

Now,

> heeding step 3's advice to "close the gaps with those around" and step 4's advice to "see the bigger picture", we unify these 3x3 patterns into a 21x21 big pattern:
>  [image]

This

> looks a lot like a QR code! Scanning it takes us to a Google web search with the word `D6yTR` in the search bar. Going to https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6yTR.png takes us to another Conway's Game of Life pattern. This time, we need only evolve it for one generation to reveal the answer:
>  [image]

Comment: So close!! You're 1/2 steps away - my hint here is '?????.png' (The solution will make much more sense than having to scroll through google)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Updated! Is the solution correct?

Comment: correct! Good job, hope it was enjoyable! :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It was! Finally my years' worth of experience with rot13(PTbY) came in handy!

Comment: haha, knew it would only be a matter of time before someone clocked all the horrible puns involved :P

Comment: @Jlee any image you upload on SE is automatically given a stack.imgur URL

Comment: @JLee you can click answer or ask new question, upload an image and copy the URL, and then just discard the draft and never post it